# field initialization and constructor sequence in Scala with inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance

Say I have a class `Graph` and a subclass `MyGraph`, `Graph` has a method `build` allowing subclass to define its own build process.

In `MyGraph`, I declare a field `node` which should be init in the build method. Thus I declare it to be null. However, when I create a `MyGraph` instance, the execution sequence first go to `MyGraph.build` and then `var node : Node = null`, which leaves the node to be null.

What is the correct way to init such a field in a method invoked from the parent?

```
class Graph {
    def build:Unit = Unit
    build
}

class MyGraph extends Graph {
    var node : Node = null
    override def build:Unit = {
        node = new Node
    }
}
```

[EDIT] More Detail about my use case: the Graph class represents a Computational Graph, which contains nodes for computation tasks. The graph has some inputs and one output. In sub classes, I need to expose the input node for user to provide input data. Here's some code providing more detail.

```
class Graph {
    val inputs = new ArrayBuffer[InputNode]()
    var output: Node = null

    def build:Unit = Unit
    build

    def newInput(): InputNode = {
        val in = new InputNode()
        inputs += in
        in
    }

    def setOutput(out: Node) {
        this.output = out
    }

    def compute():Unit = {
        inputs.foreach(_.computeAndForward())
    }
}

class LinearRegGraph extends Graph {
    var w : InputNode = null
    var x : InputNode = null
    var b : InputNode = null

    override def build:Unit = {
        w = newInput()
        x = newInput()
        b = newInput()
        val mul = new MulNode(w,x)
        val add = new AddNode(mul, b)
        setOutput(add) 
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    val graph = new LinearRegGraph()

    graph.x.setData(...)
    graph.w.setData(...)
    graph.b.setData(...)

    graph.compute()
    graph.output.getData()
}
```

I currently use the following temporary solution. However, this code is vulnerable to the implementation of node building sequence and I don't like it.

```
class LinearRegGraph extends Graph {
    def w = inputs(0)
    def x = inputs(1)
    def b = inputs(2)

    override def build:Unit = {
        val w = newInput()
        val x = newInput()
        val b = newInput()
        val mul = new MulNode(w,x)
        val add = new AddNode(mul, b)
        setOutput(add) 
    }
}
```

Comment: if you could give more details on your particular use case I can help you get through some refactoring

Comment: @acidghost Sure! I have added a more detailed explanation about the problem I am tackling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you to avoid using `var` and try to refactor you code to use a more functional approach using `val` instead.

As the code is now, the only solution I can think of is the following:

```
trait Graph

case class MyGraph(node: Node) extends Graph

val myGraph = MyGraph(new Node)
```

But more details on your specific problem might yield more suitable solutions.

**EDIT:** You could do the following

```
abstract class Graph {
    val inputs = new ArrayBuffer[InputNode]()
    val output: Option[Node] = None

    def newInput(): InputNode = {
        val in = new InputNode()
        inputs += in
        in
    }

    def compute():Unit = {
        inputs.foreach(_.computeAndForward())
    }
}

class LinearRegGraph extends Graph {
    val w: InputNode = newInput()
    val x: InputNode = newInput()
    val b: InputNode = newInput()

    val output = {
        val mul = new MulNode(w,x)
        Some(new AddNode(mul, b))
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    val graph = new LinearRegGraph()

    graph.x.setData(...)
    graph.w.setData(...)
    graph.b.setData(...)

    graph.compute()
    graph.output.get.getData()
}
```

I removed the `build` method and used the constructor instead to initialize values. I also initialized the output node to `None` in `Graph` and to `Some(add)` in `LinearRegGraph`.

If you instead don't want to use `Option` because `Graph` will never have output you could try the following:

```
trait Graph {
    val inputs = new ArrayBuffer[InputNode]()
    def output: Node

    def newInput(): InputNode = {
        val in = new InputNode()
        inputs += in
        in
    }

    def compute():Unit = {
        inputs.foreach(_.computeAndForward())
    }
}

class LinearRegGraph extends Graph {
    val w: InputNode = newInput()
    val x: InputNode = newInput()
    val b: InputNode = newInput()

    override def output = {
        val mul = new MulNode(w,x)
        new AddNode(mul, b)
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    val graph = new LinearRegGraph()

    graph.x.setData(...)
    graph.w.setData(...)
    graph.b.setData(...)

    graph.compute()
    graph.output.getData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Just one concern of using constructor instead of a build method: this will leave all intermediate variables such as `mul` and `add` end up as class variables, which I don't want to keep. If I build a large graph, there will be tons of such variables. I would rather keep them as local variables. Do you have any suggestions how to do that in an elegant manner?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just move the variables that you want to be local inside a block `{}`

Comment: Just be aware / careful that in the second version of the code I posted, `output` is defined as a method so that each time you use `output` there will be a method invocation and the output value will be recomputed.

Comment: This is really a nice solution now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should really avoid using Java's `null` in Scala.

One should prefer using an `Option[Node]` if your field is not defined all the time, or in your case, if you just want your field to wait to be initialized **and the field does not have any risk of being accessed before initialization**, you could use this syntax:

```
class MyGraph extends Graph {
  var node: Node = _
  override def build: Unit {
    node = new Node
  }
}
```

Source : [alvinalexander.com](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-null-values-option-uninitialized-variables)

Comment: This is cool! I didn't know you can do this in scala before. Thanks!